# Light Inside a Spherical Droplet

Tags: visible-light, photons, scattering, absorption, photon-emission

Suppose that a monochromatic light beam of wavelength $\lambda$ bounces around inside a perfectly spherical droplet of glycerol (radius $r$, refractive index $n$, density $\rho$, molar mass $M$) surrounded by air, undergoing total internal reflection (at an angle $\theta$ from the normal to the surface of the sphere at the point of reflection). How will this light beam get affected by scattering and absorption by the glycerol molecules, *quantitatively* speaking? For example, what fraction of the light beam will get scattered and what fraction will get absorbed and then re-emitted? Will the light be scattered or re-emitted in any preferential direction? What distance will the light beam travel before its intensity drops off by a factor of $1/e$?

Comment: Understand how a rainbow is formed might help you to answer some of your own questions?